# Excel VBA: Convert Cells to Range using Address

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a module to import text into an Excel workbook. After it imports, I want to format the data as a table. The problem I have is that the import will never have the same range.

I'm using the following code, but it throws an error, Run-time error '424': Object required.

```
Sub ImportRange()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim lCol As Long
  Dim rng As Range

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")

  lRow = ws.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  lCol = ws.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

  Set rng = ws.Cells(lRow, lCol).Address(True, True)

  'MsgBox Cells(lRow, lCol).Address(True, True)

End Sub
```

I've done quite a bit of searching, but I have been unable to find an answer or figure out how I should be doing this.

The end result would look something like this in the code with the start of the range always being set to $A$1:

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$AM$90"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Import"
```

Comment: You do not use `Address` when setting a range: `Set rng = ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)` then you can do `msgbox rng.Address(1,1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner The MsgBox was just to verify what I was doing. I need to be able to substitute with the Range ("$A$1:RANGE").

Comment: it would be `Range("A1",rng)`

Comment: You don't need Range ("$A$1:RANGE"). Just set your range to the target directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to set a range to the used range on a sheet, it can be done simpler:

```
Set rng = ws.UsedRange
```

Obviously, you need to make sure that the usedrange on that sheet properly represents your imported data.

To convert the range to a table:

```
Dim Import_Table As ListObject
Set Import_Table = ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=rng, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
Import_Table.Name = "Import"
```

Note: the code is for Excel 2010. For later versions, replace XlListObjectHasHeaders with HasHeaders

Comment: Thank you for both making me feel dumb AND giving me the right answer!  Works perfectly. Enjoy the rest of your day!